# WPF Custom Canvas to Bitmap redrawing incorrectly

Tags: wpf, canvas

I have implemented a custom canvas similar to WPF DrawTools (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22776/WPF-DrawTools). I implemented flood fill tool by converting the canvas to a bitmap, performing the flood fill algorithm, then writing the bitmap back to the canvas.

The problem I am having is that the canvas redraws incorrectly. The canvas stays in the correct position relative to the window, but the drawing within the canvas will shift based on the offset. Here is the relative code that performs the conversion:

```
    public static WriteableBitmap GetBitmap(CCDrawingCanvas canvas) {
        // Local variables
        double dpi = 96d;

        // Get the size of the canvas
        System.Windows.Size size = new System.Windows.Size((int)canvas.ActualWidth, (int)canvas.ActualHeight);

        // Measure and arrange the surface
        Point relativePoint = canvas.TransformToAncestor(Application.Current.MainWindow)
                          .Transform(new Point(0, 0));
        canvas.Measure(size);
        canvas.Arrange(new Rect(size));

        RenderTargetBitmap source = new RenderTargetBitmap(
            (int)canvas.ActualWidth,
            (int)canvas.ActualHeight,
            dpi,
            dpi,
            PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        canvas.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform(relativePoint.X, relativePoint.Y);
        source.Render(canvas);

        return new WriteableBitmap(source);
    }
```

When the first line is drawn, the canvas and drawing will render properly. Every new line added after that will shift every child element of the canvas down by `relativePoint.Y` and over by `relativePoint.X`.

If I remove the relativePoint transform and return the WriteableBitmap, the canvas is drawn at position (0, 0) relative to the entire Window. This causes a problem by overlapping other control elements that are in this position.

I have included two images showing the position after the first line is drawn and the position after the second line is drawn.

First line drawn at the very top of the canvas element.
[image: First line drawn on the left]
Second line is drawn at the very top of the canvas, but the redraw forces it down by relativePoint.Y
[image: Second line drawn to the right]

UPDATE 04/05/2014: I have discovered a temporary solution. The process is changed by first getting the location of the visual element relative to the window, then arranging the canvas based on a (0, 0) location. After the `RenderTargetBitmap.Render()` method is called, the canvas is arranged again relative to the stored point. Here is the updated code. I would still like to know how to perform this more elegantly as this fix is rather sloppy.

```
    public static WriteableBitmap GetBitmap(CCDrawingCanvas canvas) {
        // Local variables
        double dpi = 96d;

        // Get the size of the canvas
        System.Windows.Size size = new System.Windows.Size((int)canvas.ActualWidth, (int)canvas.ActualHeight);

        // Measure and arrange the surface based at a location of (0, 0) to write the bitmap properly
        canvas.Measure(size);
        Point relativePoint = canvas.TransformToAncestor(Application.Current.MainWindow)
                          .Transform(new Point(0, 0));
        canvas.Arrange(new Rect(size));

        RenderTargetBitmap source = new RenderTargetBitmap(
            (int)canvas.Width,
            (int)canvas.Height,
            dpi,
            dpi,
            PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        source.Render(canvas);

        // Arrange the canvas back to its original position.
        canvas.Arrange(new Rect(relativePoint, size));

        return new WriteableBitmap(source);
    }
```

Comment: There is no answer here, and I'm also searching for the solution. So up